# Raw bytes to unicode in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a service which returns emoticons and this is the format

```
\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\x84
```

I want to convert it to unicode `\U0001f601` so that I can eventually use this to get a html encoding of the emoticon to display on a shiny app.

```
stri_trans_general("\U0001f601", "[^\\u0000-\\u007f] any-hex/xml")
```

[1] "😁"

OR if there is a way to go from `\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\x84` to `&#x1F601;` that will work too.